# Why can I not modify the result of an unboxing conversion?

Tags: c#, il, boxing, unboxing

```
struct Point
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
void Main()
{
    Point p;
    p.x = 1;
    p.y = 1;
    Object o = p;
    ((Point) o).x = 4; // error
    ((Point) o).x = 5; // error
    ((Point) o).x = 6; // error
    p = (Point) o  // expect 6
}
```

Why doesn't it compile to

```
ldloc.1 // o
unbox Point
ldc.i4.4
stfld Point.x
```

Where C++ CLI allows it.

For those who don't know, `unbox` is [not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.unbox.aspx) required to create a copy of [value types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx), instead it pushes a pointer to the value on to the stack.
Only assignment would create a copy.

Comment: You'd be modifying a copy of the structure; a copy that you immediately throw away.  It could compile, but if it did it wouldn't work properly and you'd just be here asking why the code doesn't work.  This is the origin of the saying, "Mutable structs are evil".

Comment: @Servy But what if I don't throw away the copy, and I would like to work with the copy? After all the mutable structs are only discouraged, not banned.

Comment: Then you'd need to store the result of the boxing operation to a variable.  That's why the line in which you do that compiles.  That's how you're "supposed" to handle this case.  Unbox the variable, mutate it, and then re-box it into the variable if that is indeed where you want it to end up.

Comment: To your edit: `For those who don't know, unbox doesn't create a copy of value types, only assignment does.`  That is incorrect.  Unboxing it *does* create a copy, even if you *don't* assign it to a variable.

Comment: @Servy I added a link, hope that helps

Comment: @colinfang But because `box` has already copied the value, then you still wouldn't be changing the original value. This would be confusing, so C# disallows it.

Comment: @colinfang If you want to follow the rules of IL, write your code in IL. But you're writing your code in C#, so your code follows the rules of C#. And there, boxing does imply copying (§ 4.3.2): “An unboxing operation […] consists of […] **copying** the value out of the instance.”

Comment: @MatthewWatson: If the C# spec recognized boxed and unboxed values as distinct types the way C++/CLI does, I don't think there would have been much confusion.  I think the designers of C# assumed that boxed value types would be immutable the way primitive wrapper types are in Java, and wrote the language spec around that assumption.  Personally, I wish that rather than having unconditional boxing, there had been an `anything` type which would hold a reference of type `Object` and accept auto-boxing, but which was distinct from a reference of type `System.Object` [which would...

Comment: ...accept references to pre-boxed objects, but would not accept unboxed value types].  Something like `IList.Add()` should accept an `anything`, but something like `Object.Equals()` should only accept `Object`.

Answer (score 12):

Because of how value types work, the boxed `Point` is a copy of the original, and "unboxing" it by casting back to `Point` creates yet another copy.  From the C# language spec (§1.3, "Types and Variables"):

> When a value of a value type is converted to type object, an object instance, also called a “box,” is allocated to hold the value, and the value is copied into that box. Conversely, when an object reference is cast to a value type, a check is made that the referenced object is a box of the correct value type, and, if the check succeeds, the value in the box is copied out.

Modifying the copy wouldn't change the original anyway, so it wouldn't make much sense to allow it.

As for C++...well...of course, the rules of C# don't necessarily apply to it.  :)  The CLR actually has quite a bit more flexibility with pointers and references than you'd first think, and C++ -- being known for such flexibility -- probably takes advantage of it.

Comment: But the code tries to look at the value of the copy, not of the original. Why can't you modify that?

Comment: The unboxed Point is a copy, the boxed version not.

Comment: Boxing itself creates a copy.  (ECMA-335, §1.8.2.4: "Boxing a value of any value type produces its boxed value; i.e., a value of the corresponding boxed type containing a bitwise copy of the original value.")

Comment: Actually, I believe C++/CLI has *more* flexibility than CLR. When it does something that's not supported, it uses the closest representation and adds some metadata. For example, `Point^` (strongly-typed box) is actually represented as `ValueType modopt(Point) modopt(IsBoxed)`.

Comment: @svick: I'd still call that working within the CLR's rules.  Even though it's not exactly built in, it can still be done entirely with features the runtime provides.  It's definitely not CLS compliant, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, because the result of unboxing is a copy of the boxed value, not the boxed value itself. And casting `object` to a value type is the definition of unboxing. So, if the compiler allowed you to do this, it would be very confusing, because the assignments wouldn't actually do anything.

I *think* the reason your code works in C++/CLI is because that language in general has more support for working (or not) with references, including strongly-typed boxes (e.g. `Point^`) and treating (some) classes as value types (e.g. using `MemoryStream` without `^`).

Comment: After boxing the original value (X), there is only 1 copy (A), and I wish to modify this copy (A) as I like. I know this is not the same as the original value (X). So after I have done with the modification, I will unbox it to get the final copy (B) that is the copy of the modified copy (A).

Comment: @colinfang I do understand that's what you wish to do, but that's not what the code you wrote would mean if it compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the [System.Runtime.CompilerService.Unsafe.Unbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.unbox?view=netcore-3.0) function:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Point p;
        p.x = 1;
        p.y = 1;
        Object o = p;
        Unsafe.Unbox<Point>(o).x = 6; // error
        p = (Point)o;  // 6
        Console.WriteLine(p.x);
    }
```

As the documentation notes, and I presume the reason it is considered unsafe, is that you must not do this with an immutable built-in type [e.g. `Unbox<int>(i) = 42`], and the system does nothing to enforce this.