# Generic class unboxing error

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class that allows me to set a value with min and max limits. If these limits are exceeded, the value is modified. Untill now I only used the double data type but I also want to use integers. I hoped that a generic class would give the right solution but I run into some problems....

```
/// <summary>
/// This method takes a default value with the min and max limits. If the value exceeds these limits it is corrected.
/// </summary>
public partial class GeneratorProperty<T>
{
    private T _value;

    private T Min { get; }

    private T Max { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="defaultValue"></param>
    /// <param name="min"></param>
    /// <param name="max"></param>
    public GeneratorProperty(T defaultValue, T min, T max)
    {
        _value = defaultValue;
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (typeof (T) == typeof (double))
            {
                var temp = (double)(object)value;
                (double)(object)_value = temp.ConstrainDouble((double)(object)Min, (double)(object)Max);
                //Cannot modify the result of an unboxing conversion
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            {
                var temp = (int)(object)value;
                (int)(object)_value = temp.ConstrainInt((int)(object)Min, (int)(object)Max);
                //Cannot modify the result of an unboxing conversion
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// </summary>
public static class Extention
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     The extension method Constrains a double using a min and max value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">Value to test</param>
    /// <param name="min">minimum limit</param>
    /// <param name="max">maximum limit</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static double ConstrainDouble(this double value, double min, double max)
    {
        if (value >= min && value <= max)
            return value;
        if (value >= max)
            return max;
        if (value <= min)
            return min;
        return 1;
    }

    public static double ConstrainInt(this int value, int min, int max)
    {
        if (value >= min && value <= max)
            return value;
        if (value >= max)
            return max;
        if (value <= min)
            return min;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

During setting of the T Value I would like to constrain based on the data type. However casting to the correct data type gives me problem? To be honest I am pretty new with generics.

Anyone with some advice or a better approach on how to solve this?

Comment: maybe *_value = (T)(object)temp.ConstrainDouble((double)(object)Min, (double)(object)Max);* works?

Comment: You should probably just make the code fully generic. Constrain `T` to `IComparable<T>` and use `CompareTo` for comparisons instead of operators.

Comment: Explanation of the error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280547/why-can-i-not-modify-the-result-of-an-unboxing-conversion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any time you are doing a specific type check on a generic type (i.e. if (typeof(T) == typeof(double))) you are probably doing something wrong.

```
public partial class GeneratorProperty<T> where T: IComparable<T>
{
    ...
    public T Value
    {
        get {... }
        set 
        {
            if (this.Max.CompareTo(value) < 0)
                this._value = this.Max;
            else if (this.Min.CompareTo(value) > 0)
                this._value = this.Min;
            else
                this._value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

One of the primary purposes of generics is to avoid caring about which types you are actually receiving and operating on. Constraints help narrow that down by specifying the parts of the type that you must have in order to make it work correctly.

In this case, you want the ability to compare them, so enforce that in your constraint.

Comment: `CompareTo` only needs to return a negative value for less than, and a positive one for greater than, not `1` or `-1`.

Comment: @Lee Good catch, forgot about that.