# Cannot modify the result of an unboxing conversion ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

So basically i need to get a row count of **Table1**. **I have created a session which stores people in Table1**, but when i create a **Session** for my **int counter** i get an **error** **"Cannot modify the result of an unboxing conversion"**. And also, I would like to ask, **how can i add row number into "issaugotasTekstas"** (my people) in  **Table1**?
Tank you for suggestions!

```
        namespace ValidWeb
    {
        public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            private String issaugotasTekstas;
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (DropDownList1.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                    DropDownList1.Items.Add("-");
                    for (int i = 14; i <= 25; i++)
                    {
                        DropDownList1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                    }
                }
                issaugotasTekstas = (string)Session["Registruoti"]; // session for added people
                RegistruotasAsmuo(issaugotasTekstas);
                int sk = DalyviuSk(Table1);
                (int)Session["Dalyviu sk"] = sk; // ERROR HERE
            }


            protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string selected = "";

                foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Selected)
                    {
                        selected += item.ToString() + " | ";
                    }
                }
                issaugotasTekstas = /*row number */ TextBox1.Text + " | " + TextBox2.Text + " | " + TextBox3.Text + " | " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + " | " + selected;
// how can i add row number for each row?
                RegistruotasAsmuo(issaugotasTekstas);
                Session["Registruoti"] = issaugotasTekstas;
            }


            private void RegistruotasAsmuo(string tekstas)
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Text = tekstas;

                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                row.Cells.Add(cell);

                Table1.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            private int DalyviuSk(Table table)
            {
                return Table1.Rows.Count;
            }

            protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Table1.Rows.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing on that line, but why aren't you just doing `Session["Dalyviu sk"] = sk;`?

Comment: [Why can I not modify the result of an unboxing conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280547/why-can-i-not-modify-the-result-of-an-unboxing-conversion)

Comment: @DavidG should'nt it matter if it's an Int? But yeah, i changed it - it works incorrectly, when i add one or more people to my Table1 it always shows Table1 Count: 2  and it won't change

Comment: You have now changed your question to something else, that's not how this site works I'm afraid.